# Access to XMLHttpRequest Blocked by CORS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http, sharepoint, cors

I have a web service via a javascript in my SP site which inserts a log into my database upon a URL click

However, in console mode, the following error is displayed. The log was not inserted as well.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://test.com:8888/MyWebServices.asmx/InsertAuditLog'
>   from origin 'http://test.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

After searching through the web, I see that I may need to include some configurations in my web.config file.

So I went to IIS, and added the following into my configuration file, and did a iisreset. But the error is still being displayed the same as the initial.

Below is the part where I added into my web.config file.

```
<configuration>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://test.com/" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="origin, accept, content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
  </customHeaders> 
</httpProtocol>
</configuration>
```

May I know where did I do wrong? Or is there a specific tag that I need to insert the above lines in? Such as system.web, or system.webServer

Comment: Does your server handle the `OPTIONS` pre-flight request? (guessing it does not - since that's the error)

Comment: let me try to remove it

Comment: removed it but the error still appear. i'll seek for other solutions. thanks!

Comment: what? no ... your problem is that your **server** may not be handling `OPTIONS` preflight request ... what did you "remove"? if anything you needed to "add" something!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this.

**Make a `global.aspx` file:**

```cs
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    var context = HttpContext.Current;  
    var response = context.Response;  
  
    // enable CORS  
    response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  
  
    if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")  
    {  
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");  
        response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");  
        response.End();  
    }  
}
```

**In your web.config:**

```xml
<system.webServer>  
    <httpProtocol>  
      <customHeaders>  
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />  
      </customHeaders>  
    </httpProtocol>  
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: why did you change the -Allow-Origin and -Allow-Methods values, and remove -Allow-Credentials header? people who don't know CORS may think you have to make those changes :p

Comment: @JaromandaX if you write -Allow-Origin="*" that means that it will allow all domain and -Allow-Methods in this method it will allow those methods(put, post, get, options,etc..)
but most time we all use post and get method.

Comment: at that time he will method his domain name like allow-origin="your domain name".